# Python equivalent to Data::Dumper - dumping raw datastructures for inspection?

Tags: python, debugging

Just getting into Python and I'm shocked to find that there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to inspect datastructures properly, the way you can using Perl's Data::Dumper module.

For example, `pprint` will display an object's __repr__ return value, rather than telling me that the value is an object and what kind of object it is.

Data::Dumper will tell you *exactly* what a datastructure contains, not silently convert Objects into strings, which is absolutely useless for data inspection purposes.

Is there any way to print a *raw* dump of a datastructure in Python? I suppose I could create something myself, essentially all it needs to do is walk a datastructure and `print(type(v), v)` but there must be something that does this well?

Edit: it's __repr__ that `pprint` resolves, not __str__ as I initially said, at least..usually?

So, I think all I really need is pprint that ignores __repr__ definitions. Does that exist?

Comment: It doesn't solve your issue completely, but you might find the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module useful, particularly [inspect.getmembers()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). With a bit of glue, this makes it convenient to do your own deep introspection.

Comment: It also occurs to me that the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module isn't confused by overriding `__repr__()`, so examining the source for that might yield some useful utility functions. Still not the pre-packaged solution for which you were hoping, however.

Answer (score 3):

[pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(someVar)
```

OK. I don't have any better answer. I always use 'pprint' or 'pformat'. You can infer the type from the strings output. I think honing that skill of knowing the type from the output is the way to go.

Or as you said, your own `print(type(v), v)`.

With python, the philosophy seems to be something like: "Don't depend on the type too much. Just get an object and use it let the runtime (tests) tell the user if they mucked up": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python

---

**After reading the comments.**

Why not monkey patch the class you want to see to print something useful:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Muahaha"

def main():
    s = Person("Santa", 1500)
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(s)

    print
    print ".. Go MONKEYS ..."
    print

    # Monkey patch the Person class so it prints nice info from now on
    Person.__repr__ = lambda p: "<%s name='%s' age=%s>" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.name, p.age)
    pprint(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

-- output --

```
matthew@speedy:~/tmp$ python monkey.py
Muahaha

.. Go MONKEYS ...

<Person name='Santa' age=1500>
```

Comment: I ran into a problem where pickle was vomiting trying to to `dumps` an array of dicts. When I `pprint` the datastructure it shows me a bunch of unicode strings. In actuality those "unicode strings" were objects with a \__repr__ (or *maybe* \__str__?) method that's returning a unicode string. I couldn't see that without manually walking the datastructure and using `type()` because `pprint` sucks for this!

Comment: @PeteD -- That's the fault of the class writer who chose to override `__repr__` in a non-helpful way.  That's not `pprint`'s fault :)

Comment: @mgilson The problem seems to be that `pprint` is not really supposed to be for data inspection, it's supposed to be a way of dumping a datastructure "in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter." But what I want is to be able to see the raw dump of a datastructure for debugging purposes, not as a way to feed it back to the interpreter. If `pprint` was for debugging it'd be bad to rely on \__repr__ functions.

Comment: You don't have a huge amount of choice when you're dealing with an object-oriented language, though - the only other option would be to recursively dump every single method and attribute, because the language doesn't have any special knowledge of how to represent these objects. That would typically be far too verbose to be useful in most circumstances. If an object is returning something unhelpful from `__repr__()` then it's pretty badly behaved, frankly - sounds like someone confused it with `__str__()`. I realise that knowing it's badly behaved is of little use to you right now, however!

Comment: Monkey patch the evil class. (Answer edited to show this now)